# Error while passing PHP data through AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to PHP and jQuery, so I have doubt when declaring PHP data in JSON format with AJAX.

I don't know how to receive the JSON data again and place it inside a PHP variable.

Here's my current attempt:

```
<?php
 $id = $_GET['id'];
  ?>


function load_topic()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_topic.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{
    tpid :"<?php print $id; ?>"
   },
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_topic').html(data);
   }
  })
 }

function load_comment()
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"fetch_comment.php",
   method:"POST",
  data:{
    "tpid" :"<?php print $id; ?>"
   },
   dataType:"JSON",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('#display_comment').html(data);
   }
  })
 }
```

Comment: Can you tell us what the error/issue is that you are seeing?

Comment: are you using any framework?

Comment: create a separate file and pass all the data to file,

Comment: I don't use any frame work and it does not show any error

Comment: My doubt is whether I declare the json data in the correct manner or not

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you don't combine server-side and client-side scripts.

Comment: ok guys forgot my stuffs please help me to pass the $id variable to to the fetch_comment,topic.php page.Is there is any simple way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to retrieve the tpid which you pass with ajax in your files fetch_comment.php and fetch_topic.php.

To do this, you simply use

```
$tpid = $_POST['tpid'];
```

This retrieves the 'tpid' which was send via the ajax post request and stores it in the variable $tpid.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: Can I able to declare simply like this in data attribute unlike json

Answer (score 0):

check by inspecting in browser under network that it is sending data or not?
if it is sending the data using method post 
then in php file where you are receiving data use
print_r($_POST);

if it print something in and it is showing in json try print_r(json_decode($_POST));

Comment: yes it print the variable content,but before i include the data option int the ajax field it works properly in the sense it return the fetched data from the database.but i want to fetch some data with the condition with the help of data i want to pass over the ajax.

Comment: without these two line my code work well ` data:{
        "tpid" :"<?php print $id; ?>"
    },
    dataType:"HTML", `

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues with your post, here:

1/ It's not clear what JSON data you are returning from `fetch_topic.php` and `fetch_comment.php`. Your code is fine, but without knowing what JSON data you are returning from those pages, it's difficult to help.

2/ The function that handles the response is a bit odd in that it will print the raw JSON data to those elements. If you want to process the JSON a bit better, i suggest something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch_comment.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
        "tpid" :"<?php print $id; ?>"
    },
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function( response )
    {
        if ( response.status == 'success' ) {
            $('#display_comment').html( response.html );
        } else {
            // handle your error here.
        }
    }
});
```

and your fetch page responds with:

```
{"status":"success","html":"<p>Here is an HTML response!<\/p>"}
```

or not use JSON and just return html from your fetch pages:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"fetch_comment.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
        "tpid" :"<?php print $id; ?>"
    },
    dataType:"HTML",
    success:function( response )
    {
        $('#display_comment').html( html );
    }
});
```

A little more clarity in your request would be super helpful.